# How to compare components of two snapshots in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube, snapshot, sonarqube5.1

In SonarQube (Sonar), how can I compare which components were analysed in two different snapshots/versions? In comparison view, I can only compare metrics. Is there a way to view components analysed in a given version/snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that's just not available.

Comment: So there is no way for me to find out which component was missing in an earlier analysis, even though i have metrics? Isn't it stored somewhere in database at least?

Comment: Sorry, no. Metrics histories are stored (at the aggregate level). Resource histories are not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although it is a quite disappointing one.